# Django redirect in an if statement not working

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am experiencing an error in Django that I can't manage to solve. After receiving a post to my endpoint I am trying to compare if the result code is equal to 0 if it's equal to 0  then I redirect to the relevant view.

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Transaction Intited Successfully. Enter PIN on your phone')

    phone_no = request.POST['client_phone'][1:]

    base_url = settings.BASE_URL
    lipa_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    Business_short_code = settings.BUSINESS_SHORTCODE
    passkey = settings.PASSKEY
    data_to_encode = Business_short_code + passkey + lipa_time
    online_password = base64.b64encode(data_to_encode.encode())
    decode_password = online_password.decode('utf-8')

    lipa = Lipa()
    access_token = lipa.get_token()
    print(access_token)
    api_url = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token}
    request = {
        "BusinessShortCode": Business_short_code,
        "Password": decode_password,
        "Timestamp": lipa_time,
        "TransactionType": "CustomerPayBillOnline",
        "Amount": "1",
        "PartyA": "254"+phone_no, 
        "PartyB": Business_short_code,
        "PhoneNumber": "254"+phone_no,  
        "CallBackURL": base_url+"/confirmation",
        "AccountReference": "Jaymoh",
        "TransactionDesc": "Channel join payment"
    }
    response = requests.post(api_url, json=request, headers=headers)
    pprint.pprint(response.json())

    rendered = render_to_string('home.html', {})
    response = HttpResponse(rendered)

    return response

return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Post data is sent to the view below:

```
def confirmation(request):
print(request.body)
if request.method == 'POST':
    response = json.loads(request.body)
    pprint.pprint(response)
    transaction_response = response['Body']['stkCallback']

    save_transaction = Transaction( 
        MerchantRequestID = transaction_response['MerchantRequestID'],
        CheckoutRequestID = transaction_response['CheckoutRequestID'],
        ResultCode = transaction_response['ResultCode'],
        ResultDesc = transaction_response['ResultDesc']
    )

    save_transaction.save()

    transaction_result = transaction_response['ResultCode']
    print("ResultCode = %s" % transaction_result)
    print(type(transaction_result))

    if transaction_result == 0:
        print('Transaction successful')
        return redirect("successfultransaction")

    else:
        print("Incomplete Transaction")
        return redirect('incompletetransaction') 

return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

The error now occurs in this view, The if statement executes and prints but the redirects never happen.

> {"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"8995-63446-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_131120191221087793","ResultCode":1,"ResultDesc":"The
>   balance is insufficient for the transaction"}}}'
>
> {'Body': {'stkCallback': {'CheckoutRequestID':
>   'ws_CO_131120191221087793',
>                             'MerchantRequestID': '8995-63446-1',
>                             'ResultCode': 1,
>                             'ResultDesc': 'The balance is insufficient for the '
>                                           'transaction'}}} {'CheckoutRequestID': 'ws_CO_131120191221087793',  'CustomerMessage':
>   'Success. Request accepted for processing',  'MerchantRequestID':
>   '8995-63446-1',  'ResponseCode': '0',  'ResponseDescription':
>   'Success. Request accepted for processing'}
>
> [13/Nov/2019 12:21:17] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 4081
>
> ResultCode = 1
>
> Incomplete Transaction
>
> [13/Nov/2019 12:21:17] "POST /confirmation HTTP/1.1" 302 0

---

Before the post in the home function, I returned a `HttpResponse()`. I don't think can be affecting the redirect in the confirmation callback function which receives the POST.

Comment: Show your urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's happen.

Look: `[13/Nov/2019 12:21:17] "POST /confirmation HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

You got a response with 302 code, that's is redirect.

Comment: But I don't think that redirect happens when the code execution gets to the else part because the execution goes on without returning anything. The page displayed is the one rendered using the **HttpResponse** on the home function before the callback